# What does it mean if (development branch) is part of the title?

Tags: development

I apologize for what is probably a stupid question, but my google- and stackoverflow-fu has failed to positively reveal the answer to my question:

What does it mean if a branch (such as `Ubuntu Utopic Unicorn (development branch)`) has the `development branch` phrase?

Does it mean that no RCs have been cut, or that the branch has not bee EOLed, or that I'm running the latest bleeding edge even if an RC has been cut?